# Change the state of progressBar using React Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

I am trying to implement React Context on this small example.
I have a Progress bar on one of the components and a Toggle context on another componenet.

I have Implemented the context but the code doesn`t give an error, it doesn't work.

I am trying to change the Progress Bar state in Componenet1 from Componenet3 which has the button to toggle the ProgressBar.

The example in the link https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-grass-pgf2b?file=/src/Component1.js

Thank you

Comment: Exactly that is the point, I want to implement react context and I don`t want to pass props through other components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with:

```
const PercentContext = React.createContext({
  percent: 0,
  setValue: (val) => {}
});

export default PercentContext;
```

Provide your "context" in `App`:

```
const [percent, setPercent] = React.useState(7);
  return (
    <PercentContext.Provider value={{ percent, setValue: setPercent }}>
      <div className="App">....
```

Then consume in your inner components:

```
<PercentContext.Consumer>
        {({ percent, setValue }) => (
          ....
```

You can learn a little more of this article on React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component)

A solution exists here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-knuth-wcugn

Comment: thank for your answer, it works. I have two questions if u don`t mind, what if i am using class component and Hook doesn`t work in the App.js? what should i do? Second why I can`t provide the state directly from Component 1 instead of going back to App.js

Comment: I noticed that codesanbox does not render the root component if its a class component. I think thats a bug in the transpiling. Why not try putting everything in Component1 including the state. so in App you would only have `<Component1 />` and you move `App` contents to Component1. You wont need to change 2 & 3.

Comment: I see. it is bug but what if it is not on codesandbox on normal IDE ? how would u do it?The thing my friend is that on the real project that i am trying to modify it is structured in the same way that i have shared in the codesandbox? and there are a lot to move which will require to change a lot of things. So this method is most simple and very helpful to me. I really thank you for that. just if i could even implement with class component in the App it would solve my problem

Comment: Fixed: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-knuth-wcugn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hi again, if u don`t mind, How do i reset the state of the progress bar when a reset button is clicked.

Comment: it should be as simple as setValue(0)?

Comment: So u mean i should wrap the reset button again with Context consumer and setValue to 0 ? I really don`t know with context it is little different? can u please show me an example

Comment: Yes! Thats the way

Comment: Yep it worked at suppose to be. what if u need to update state in componentDidmound or a function outside the jsx?

Comment: You would pass the set value method via props.. right?

Comment: With React Context I have tried that doesn`t work, it works only on the props drilling method

Comment: It should work.. you are doing something wrong.